How to get the signedresources id for uploading the model using resumable upload in OSS (Data Management API)
I'm currently working on uploading a model to a bucket in chunks, which requires utilizing resumable upload functionality from Data Management API. However, I've encountered a hurdle: to proceed with the resumable upload, I need the signed resources ID. Could someone please guide me on how to access the signed resources ID?
I've checked the Autodesk documentation regarding resumable uploads, but I'm still unsure how to obtain this ID. Here's the link to the relevant documentation for reference:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/signedresources-:id-resumable-PUT/#resource-information
I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to proceed with obtaining the signed resources ID. Thank you in advance for your help!
Previously, I was able to upload files to the bucket using the Model Derivative API, where I received a signed URL for the upload process. For those interested, here's the documentation link for that process:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-source-file-containing-xref/task2-upload_source_file_to_oss/

You need to call this endpoint: 
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signed-POST/
See this example: 
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/signedresources-:id-PUT/#example-1
There is also another way to upload using direct to S3 API calls: 
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/direct-s3-upload-and-download-sdks
If you are using the SDKs that the tutorials use too then they have an uploadResources utility function that uploads files in chunks: 
https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/
We have also new SDKs that I think have the same functionality: 
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/call-feedback-net-sdk-beta 
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/call-feedback-nodejstypescript-sdk-beta

Hi Adam,
Thank you for your response.
I tried to use the endpoint to acquire the signedUrl, but encountered a 404 Not Found error in the response. Could you please advise on potential causes for this issue?
Additionally, I want to confirm: do we not obtain the signed resources ID directly, but rather retrieve it using the signedUrl?

Could you please log a case with us through https://aps.autodesk.com/contact-support and provide screenshots of e.g. the Postman request you are sending and the reply?
